# Add the selected option from one select to another select in ReactJs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a select inside a ReactJs component, which contains some options, and I would like the selected option to be added to another select that is in another component.
Example:

```
const conponent1 = () => {
return <>
  <select>
    <option value="">Select a option</option>
      <option value="1">Option 1</option>
      <option value="2">Option 2</option>
      <option value="3">Option 3</option>
    </select>
    <component2 />
  </>
} 

const component2 = () => {
return <>
  <select>
    <option value="">Select a option</option>\
    //It does not contain any options because one has not yet been chosen in the previous select.
    </select>
  </>
}
```

The user selects option 2, so this option must be added to the select of the second component.

```
const conponent1 = () => {
return <>
  <select>
    <option value="">Select a option</option>
      <option value="1">Option 1</option>
      <option value="2">Option 2</option> // Chosen option.
      <option value="3">Option 3</option>
    </select>
    <component2 />
  </>
} 

const component2 = () => {
return <>
  <select>
    <option value="">Select a option</option>\
    <option value="2">Option 2</option> // It was added because it was the chosen option.
    </select>
  </>
}
```

Comment: You will have to store the selection of the first `select` to the state of `component1` and pass that value as a prop to `component2` and use it to populate that select.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://codesandbox.io/s/nice-cartwright-6zulx?file=/src/index.js:0-69

```
import { useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

const baseOptions = [
  {
    label: "option 1",
    value: "1"
  },
  {
    label: "option 2",
    value: "2"
  },
  {
    label: "option 3",
    value: "3"
  }
];

const Select = ({ options, onChange, value, disabledOptions = [] }) => (
  <select onChange={onChange} value={value}>
    <option disabled value="">
      select an option
    </option>
    {options.map((option, i) => (
      <option
        key={option.value}
        value={option.value}
        disabled={
          disabledOptions.findIndex((o) => o.value === option.value) !== -1
        }
      >
        {option.label}
      </option>
    ))}
  </select>
);

export default function App() {
  const [selectedOptions, setSelectedOptions] = useState([]);

  const [firstSelectValue, setFirstSelectValue] = useState("");
  const [secondSelectValue, setSecondSelectValue] = useState("");

  const handleFirstSelectChange = (e) => {
    const value = e.target.value;
    const option = baseOptions.find((o) => o.value === value);
    setSelectedOptions([...selectedOptions, option]);
    setFirstSelectValue(option.value);
  };

  const handleSecondSelectChange = (e) => {
    setSecondSelectValue(e.target.value);
  };
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Select
        options={baseOptions}
        onChange={handleFirstSelectChange}
        value={firstSelectValue}
        disabledOptions={selectedOptions}
      />

      <Select
        options={selectedOptions}
        onChange={handleSecondSelectChange}
        value={secondSelectValue}
      />

      <div>Selected Value: {secondSelectValue}</div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, I used the arrow function with the variable of type useState([]), passed it to the component as a props and it worked!

Answer (score 0):

If you use the exact same select, why don't you use the same component and add options with props?
Something like onchange of first select setstate of selected option.
Then give the state as props when you render the second select like this.state.map(option=>{option})

Comment: In the case I just gave you is just an example, in what I am trying to do, there is a component that contains within it several other selects that wait for you to select an option so that the selected option is added as an option to your selects.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like:

```
import React from "react";

const App = () => {
  const [options, setOptions] = React.useState([]);

  const Conponent2 = () => {
    return(
      <select>
        <option value="-1">Select a option</option>
        {
          options.map(el => <option value={el.value}>{el.text}</option>)
        }
      </select>
    )
  };

  const Conponent1 = ({onChange}) => {
    return(
      <>
      <select onChange={onChange}>
        <option value="-1">Select a option</option>
        <option value="1">Option 1</option>
        <option value="2">Option 2</option>
      </select>

      <Conponent2 />
      </>
    )
  };
  
  const onChange = (e) => {
    setOptions([{
      value: e.target.value,
      text: e.target.options[e.target.selectedIndex].text,
    }])
  }

  return <Conponent1 onChange={onChange} />;
}

export default App;
```

[image: Edit Stack-overflow]

And if you want to keep the prev selected options you can:

```
setOptions([...options, {
  value: e.target.value,
  text: e.target.options[e.target.selectedIndex].text,
}])
```